# Undo reshape to original data.table format

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

Given the following data table describing the production inputs for the manufacture of cars in countries AT and BE:

```
DT <- data.table( Abb=c("AT", "AT", "BE", "BE"),input=c("iron", "glass", "iron", "glass"),AT_Car=c(5,5,0,5),BE_Car=c(0,3,2,2))

> DT
   Abb input AT_Car BE_Car
1:  AT  iron      5      0
2:  AT glass      5      3
3:  BE  iron      0      2
4:  BE glass      5      2
```

I have used the reshape function in order to compute something:

```
DT2 <- reshape(DT,direction='wide',idvar='Abb', timevar='input')

> DT2
   Abb AT_Car.iron BE_Car.iron AT_Car.glass BE_Car.glass
1:  AT           5           0            5            3
2:  BE           0           2            5            2
```

Once modified, I need to convert DT2 back to the original format of DT. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [development version of data.table, `v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) has new features for `melt` and `dcast` data.table methods. Check the [Efficient reshaping using data.tables](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) for more details, and the [Getting started Wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for other vignettes.

**Long-to-Wide - `dcast` accepts multiple columns:**

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
DT.c = dcast(DT, Abb ~ input, value.var = c('AT_Car', 'BE_Car'))
#    Abb AT_Car_glass AT_Car_iron BE_Car_glass BE_Car_iron
# 1:  AT            5           5            3           0
# 2:  BE            5           0            2           2
```

**Wide-to-Long - `melt` also accepts a list for `measure.vars`:**

```
DT.m = melt(DT.c, id = "Abb", measure.vars = patterns("^AT_Car", "^BE_Car"), 
             variable.name = "input", value.name = c("AT_Car", "BE_Car"))
setattr(DT.m$input, 'levels', c("glass", "iron"))
#    Abb input AT_Car BE_Car
# 1:  AT glass      5      3
# 2:  BE glass      5      2
# 3:  AT  iron      5      0
# 4:  BE  iron      0      2
```

Comment: Thank you Arun, it does as intended. Would it be possible to write it in a way in which you don't need to specify the names? Specifically for the 'measure.vars' variable. My real data is much bigger than this example.

Comment: David, glad. Using regex might be a way to automatically extract the names. But I've not yet worked on how best to name columns and set levels automatically. Would update the post when/if I manage.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using the same reshape function wide-to-long seems to work:

```
DT3 <- reshape(DT2,direction='long',idvar='Abb', timevar='input')

> DT3
   Abb input AT_Car.iron BE_Car.iron
1:  AT  iron           5           0
2:  BE  iron           0           2
3:  AT glass           5           3
4:  BE glass           5           2
```

However, the column order is altered...any ideas on how to keep it to the original order?

Comment: You already used `reshape` in your question. Also, this will be very slow on a big data set, and if you don't care about such things, why using `data.table` in the first place? You have been provided with the idiomatic/fast/efficient/simple `data.table` approach, why are you trying to stick with `reshape`?

Comment: I cannot install Rtools at work and everyone is on holidays so I am trying to find a solution within the existing capabilities...